# Is there a way to pass multiple values into rangeOfString?

Tags: validation, swift

I'm trying to do a check to see if a user-entered URL is actually a local IP address by checking if it contains either *192., 10. or 172*. I'm hoping it's possible to just do something like my example below rather than running three separate checks.

```
 if url.rangeOfString("192. | 10. | 172.") != nil { 

       var validLOCAL = regexValidated(httpURL, isSearch: false)

       if validLocalURL == true {
           return localURL
       } else {
           return ""
 }
```

I know I've seen stuff like this in jQuery but I'm not sure if it's possible in this situation.

### Is there a way to pass multiple values into rangeOfString?

Comment: Notice the term "regex" in your code. That means regular expression. So why not use a regular expression?

Comment: @matt I'm routing three different possibilities into different regular expressions validators. 1st is a URL, 2nd is a search query and 3rd is a local IP address. In other words, this is just an initial check to determine which regex to send the string to.

Comment: I didn't follow any of that. :( See if my answer is of any use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSString's `rangeOfSubstring:options:` where the `options:` is `. RegularExpressionSearch` - and now you are doing exactly what your proposed pseudo-code is doing. Example:

```
let target = "192.168.0.0"
let pat = "^(192\\.|10\\.|172\\.)"
let r = target.rangeOfString(pat, options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
```

If not found, `r` will be `nil`.

Comment: So I create a new regex, pass it in rangeOfSubstring as the first parameter and use .RegularExpressionSearch as the second parameter. Thanks matt

Comment: I'm just guessing on the `^` but I'm assuming that's the sort of thing you have in mind.